# Safari rendering issue when layout changes

Tags: safari, render

Safari 5 is giving me a strange rendering issue. It's a JS/jQuery belt of images. When you click one it removes the "selected" class from the currently selected image and applies it to the one you just selected, moving the blue border to show the change. It also updates some other content it retrieves from a JSON feed.

The problem is that when the content changes in size and pushes the belt, the border rendering gets broken apart. The best way to see it is in this image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/niwis.jpg

Anyone seen anything like this before? Here is the markup.

```
<span id="photo-index">1 of 21</span>
<span id="photo-caption"><span class="count">1.</span>bla bla bla</span>
<div class="jquery-belt" id="article-photo-belt">
    <div class="window">
        <ul class="clearFix" style="width: 2232px;">
            <li class="selected">
                <a href="#"><img width="75" height="75" alt="..." title="..." src="..."></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img width="75" height="75" alt="..." title="..." src="..."></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img width="75" height="75" alt="..." title="..." src="..."></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img width="75" height="75" alt="..." title="..." src="..."></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <span class="btn next"><a href="#"></a></span>
</div>
```